# Pie Chart with nplot in c#

Tags: c#, charts, pie-chart

I am currently working with Nplot to set up some graphic charts in c#.
I find out that there were no example about setting up a pie chart with Nplot Library!
Could someone confirm me or tell me how I can have my pie Chart with nplot?

Thank you in advance for your help.